# Given a vector, how to find all subsets of the vector and the original indices of

Tags: c++

Given a vector, how to find all subsets of the vector accompanied by the original indices from the vector?

For example given the vector,

```
vector<float> numbers {1.3, 0.5, 2.4};
```

get subsets:

```
{}, {1.3}, {0.5}, {2.4}, {1.3, 2.4}, {0.5, 2.4}, {1.3, 0.5}, {1.3, 0.5, 2.4}
```

and corresponding indices for each subset:

```
{}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}.
```

Comment: You should provide a sample code on what you have worked on.

Comment: Hint: solving the second part first only requires knowing the size of the original vector. Once you have all the `indicies`, you can use it to look up in `numbers`

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment? :-P

The following function will generate *index subsets*. The `indices` argument is just a temporary scratch variables.

```
void getIndexSubsets(
  int l, int u, std::vector<int>* indices, 
  std::vector<std::vector<int>>* result) {
  if (l == u) {
    result->push_back(*indices);
  } else {
    int next = l + 1;
    getIndexSubsets(next, u, indices, result);
    indices->push_back(l);
    getIndexSubsets(next, u, indices, result);
    indices->pop_back();
  }
}
```

It is used like this:

```
  std::vector<float> numbers{1.3, 0.5, 2.4};

  std::vector<int> indices;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> indexResult;

  getIndexSubsets(0, numbers.size(), &indices, &indexResult);
```

The index subsets will be output in `indexResult`. Given the index subsets, we can compute the value subsets using this function:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> getValueSubsets(
  const std::vector<float>& srcValues,
  const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& src) {

  std::vector<std::vector<float>> dst;
  for (const auto& inds: src) {
    std::vector<float> x;
    for (auto i: inds) {
      x.push_back(srcValues[i]);
    }
    dst.push_back(x);
  }
  return dst;
}
```

Invoking it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> valueResult = getValueSubsets(numbers, indexResult);
```

The full solution reads like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void getIndexSubsets(
  int l, int u, std::vector<int>* indices, 
  std::vector<std::vector<int>>* result) {
  if (l == u) {
    result->push_back(*indices);
  } else {
    int next = l + 1;
    getIndexSubsets(next, u, indices, result);
    indices->push_back(l);
    getIndexSubsets(next, u, indices, result);
    indices->pop_back();
  }
}

std::vector<std::vector<float>> getValueSubsets(
  const std::vector<float>& srcValues,
  const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& src) {

  std::vector<std::vector<float>> dst;
  for (const auto& inds: src) {
    std::vector<float> x;
    for (auto i: inds) {
      x.push_back(srcValues[i]);
    }
    dst.push_back(x);
  }
  return dst;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const std::vector<T>& src) {
  s << "{";
  bool f = true;
  for (auto x: src) {
    s << (f? "" : " ") << x;
    f = false;
  }
  s << "}";
  return s;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<float> numbers{1.3, 0.5, 2.4};

  std::vector<int> indices;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> indexResult;

  getIndexSubsets(0, numbers.size(), &indices, &indexResult);

  std::vector<std::vector<float>> valueResult = getValueSubsets(numbers, indexResult);

  for (int i = 0; i < indexResult.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "Subset inds=" << indexResult[i] << " values=" << valueResult[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When executed, it will output this:

```
Subset inds={} values={}
Subset inds={2} values={2.4}
Subset inds={1} values={0.5}
Subset inds={1 2} values={0.5 2.4}
Subset inds={0} values={1.3}
Subset inds={0 2} values={1.3 2.4}
Subset inds={0 1} values={1.3 0.5}
Subset inds={0 1 2} values={1.3 0.5 2.4}
```

Comment: In addition, duplicates should be avoided more carefully, https://wandbox.org/permlink/7VXHGqgnZE5A3qWw .

Comment: Not homework, just a genuine problem which could be done quickly in Python but I had a hard time with C++.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would it be a good idea to provide the Python code in the question? Hiroki pointed out that that duplicate elements are not taken into consideration, in my response. That is, I assume that the input numbers array is already a set. How does your Python code deal with that?